# Java jLabel.setText() method overloading not with String

Tags: java, swing

In a jLabel component, say I have this codes,

```
JLabel jLabel = new JLabel();
jLabel.setText( 123 ) ;
```

It generates error. But writing this,

```
jLabel.setText( 123 + "" ) ;
```

force to int part to be a string. But I don't think writing int like that way is a good idea! Does this method has any overloaded siblings grasping not a String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much you can do here, `setText` only takes a `String` parameter. Alternatively, you could do `jLabel.setText(Integer.toString(123))`, if you find this more readable.

As for `123 + ""` part, whenever you add some variables and at least one of them is a `String`, the compiler will automatically call `toString` on the others and will concatenate all the strings. `somevar + ""` (empty string) is a quick way of calling `somevar.toString()`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is correct. You are passing a number to a method that wants the string. The reason the second method works is that the jvm is taking the number and the string, and adding them together, which returns a string, which is why it works. Your other option is to do something Integer.toString(123);